# Rack::Deflater returning error 330 on all pageloads (except public files)

Tags: http, gzip, jruby, rack

jRuby 1.7.3, Rack 1.5.2 (with jRuby-Rack && Trinidad)

After upgrading jRuby && Rack && jRuby-Rack, suddenly all my pageloads fail out with Error 330 unless they refer to a public file.

I invoke my application by rackup's **config.ru**.
I **use Rack::Deflater** in that.

Before I updated, everything worked great. I didn't update them one at a time, otherwise I'd know which one caused the defect.

I searched high and low for why, but got no clues. Trinidad's configuration I set compression, or I try to... Google PageSpeed is complaining my data is not gzipped.

Where is this alien or ghost living? I should probably charge it rent or make sure it gets on the lease if I am doomed to begin waiting for upstream code revisions.

Comment: So far only reverting back to Rack 1.4.1 solves this.